# Problem with "instanceof" with generic outer class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

The following code does not compile:

```
class OuterClass<T> {

    class BaseClass { }

    class SubClass extends BaseClass { }

    public void test(BaseClass myObject) {
        boolean b = (myObject instanceof SubClass);
    }
}
```

The error message on method `test()` is: "*Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type MyOuterClass.MySubClass. Use the form MySubClass instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime*"

So how do I determine whether the variable is of type `BaseClass`? I have tried all of the following and they don't work:

```
boolean b1 = (myObject instanceof SubClass);
boolean b2 = (myObject instanceof SubClass<T>);
boolean b3 = (myObject instanceof SubClass<?>);
boolean b4 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass.SubClass);
boolean b5 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass<T>.SubClass);
boolean b6 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass<?>.SubClass);
boolean b7 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass.SubClass<T>);
boolean b8 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass.SubClass<?>);
```

I think this problem is independent of the JVM version, but just in case, I am using Sun's version 1.6.0_22-b04.

Comment: Your line for "b4" should have worked, assuming you get rid of the "My" prefixes.

Comment: Instead of testing for classes, why not test for an interface? I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that typo, highlycaffeinated; I have removed the prefix "My".

Comment: @Dan - if one of the answers help you then please do accept one. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to highlycaffeinated and Nulldevice for pointing out that b4 and b6 are correct.

I have discovered that this is a bug in the version of Eclipse that I was using. (I was using Ganymede, and it was fixed when I upgraded to Helios.)

Just for the record, I have filed it as [Eclipse bug 353354](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353354).

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but if we modify the example as follows, it does compile:

```
class OuterClass<T> {

    class InnerClass { }

    public void test(Object myObject) {
        boolean b1 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass.InnerClass);     // Works
        boolean b2 = (myObject instanceof OuterClass<?>.InnerClass);  // Also works
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the remaining problem? Do you want to know *why*?

Answer (score 1):

Your code for b4 is correct. At least for 1.6.0_23.

```
class OuterClass<T> {

    class BaseClass { }

    class SubClass extends BaseClass { }

    public void test(BaseClass myObject) {
        boolean b = (myObject instanceof OuterClass.SubClass);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass<Integer> outerClass = new OuterClass<Integer>();
        OuterClass<Integer>.BaseClass b = outerClass.new BaseClass();
        OuterClass<Integer>.SubClass s = outerClass.new SubClass();
        outerClass.test(b);
        outerClass.test(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer anything at all

Answer (score 1):

recalling painful experience chasing subtle bugs related to named non-static inner classes, I just couldn't resist to see what happens if I make 'em static...

```
class OuterClass<T> {

    static class BaseClass { }

    static class SubClass extends BaseClass { }

    public void test(BaseClass myObject) {
        boolean b = (myObject instanceof SubClass);
    }
}
```

...and voila! compiler errors have gone with the wind